# MailChimp adding [BC-SP][MKTG] to the start of all email subject lines

Tags: mailchimp

I have recently started sending emails using MailChimp. I have noticed that at the beginning of all of my subject lines, the letters [BC-SP][MKTG] are appearing and I'm not sure why. 
I have not typed these letters in myself. They do not appear when I am creating the email or in the 'Preview' mode, however when I send an email they appear at the beginning of the subject line. This has happened with every email that I have sent so far, and is affecting multiple receiving account types (e.g. hotmail, Outlook).
Has anybody else come across this problem or have any idea what is causing it or how I can fix it?

Thank you!
Steph

Comment: Are you sure it mail chimp adding it and not a spam filter at your ISP?  Do other people at different domains get that in the subject too?

Comment: Hi Stephen. Thanks for your suggestion - yes it is being added in all three of the mail providers that I have tested